# get_acs not pulling tract geography for Wilson County in Texas in 2009?

Tags: tidycensus

The following code seems to be missing geography information for tracts in Wilson County in Texas for 2009 using the 5-year ACS.  Any ideas of what could be wrong?

```
racedat09 <- get_acs(geography = "tract",
                 state = "TX",
                 year = 2009,
                 geometry = TRUE,
                 output = "wide",
                 table = "B03002",
                 cache_table = T,
                 survey = "acs5")
```

Here are the tail of the results:

[image]

Edit/update: it seems that get_acs census tract codes do not match those of the census tiger shapefiles.  Those in the tiger files start with 980 (not 000).  There may be something else going on as the tiger file for 2009 shows 9 tracts but the get_acs pulls at least 11, which does not match either.